# C# - Convert IEnumerable to Dictionary<object,string>

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a WPF `UserControl`. For this I implemented an `ItemSource DependecyProperty` like this:

```
private IEnumerable MisItems;
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(TextBoxAutoComplete), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged)));

    private static void OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as TextBoxAutoComplete;
        if (control != null)
            control.OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.OldValue, (IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        MisItems = newValue;
        // Remove handler for oldValue.CollectionChanged
        var oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (null != oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            oldValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
        }
        // Add handler for newValue.CollectionChanged (if possible)
        var newValueINotifyCollectionChanged = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (null != newValueINotifyCollectionChanged)
        {
            newValueINotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged);
        }

    }

    void newValueINotifyCollectionChanged_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do your stuff here.
    }
```

The `ItemsSource` property is represented by a `IEnumerable` Object. Now I need to convert it to a `Dictionary<object,string`> in this function:

```
protected SearchResult DoSearch(string searchTerm)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
            //var ItemsText = MisItems.GetType();
            var p = (List<string>)MisItems;

             /*sr.Results = ItemsText.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }).Where(x=>x.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.ToUpper()))
            .ToDictionary(a => (object)a.i, a => a.x);*/

            return sr;
        }
        else return new SearchResult();           
    }
```

How can i make the transition?

**EDIT**
More info:
My viewmodel has this property:

```
public List<EnumeradorWCFModel> Clientes { get; set; }
```

The data for this property is returned by a `WCF service`:

```
Clientes = _svc.Clientes_Enum(sTicket, "");
```

Then I wanted my `UserControl` to bind to this property. I create my control like this:

```
<autocomplete:TextBoxAutoComplete x:Name="Clientes"  ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Clientes}" DisplayMemberPath="Descripcion" Height="25"/>
```

Comment: What was wrong with your commented out code (other than you likely should be using String comparison rather than the .ToUppers)

Comment: In the commented out code shouldn't you have done `Where(x=>x.x.ToString()...`?  Currently you are calling `ToString` on your anonymous class.

Comment: Well, commented line and above works if ItemsSource is a simple array of strings. But when I set dataContext to a complex line, wont work, because this line var p = (List<string>)MisItems; of course thows exeption.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: This is probably not a good idea...  would you use an `object` for a key to a dictionary?

Answer (score 12):

[s]Alright. You posted a lot of code (that I personally think is unnecessary for what you're trying to do).

Let's slim it down.

You have an `IEnumerable<string>` to start out, correct? Good.

There's a `ToDictionary()` extension method in the LINQ libraries. Documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary(v=vs.100).aspx).

So what you need to do is the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> myEnumerableOfStrings = new List<string>();

Dictionary<object, string> dictionary = myEnumerableOfStrings.ToDictionary(value => (object) value);
```

[And here's a Fiddle as an example.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hXg7s3)

Alright, so we have just an `IEnumerable` with no strong type. (First I've ever seen or heard of this being done, but the same principles should apply.)

We need to create a local dictionary and iterate over that collection.

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<object, string>();
IEnumerable myCollection = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in myCollection)
{
    // This might be fun if you get two of the same object in the collection.
    // Since this key is based off of the results of the GetHashCode() object in the base object class.
    myDictionary.Add((object) item, item.ToString());
}
```

[Here's an example of that.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OBpZjz)

Comment: Thanks Cameron for your help, and sorry if is too much code. Your presumtion is not 100% right. I have a dependenceProperty defined like an IEnumerable, not IEnumerable<string>, so I have no .ToDictionary method. Please see my update.

Comment: @ericpap So you don't have a strong type? Cool. It makes this problem a *little* more complicated, but not that bad.

Comment: Thank you! Well this seems to get more complicated. Your code works, but the string part is empty, so I suppose that item.ToString() is returning null or empty. I Try myDictionary.Add((object)item, item.GetType().GetProperty("Descripcion").ToString()); but same result. The Name of the property should be linked with DisplayMemberPath property

Answer (score 2):

The above answer's example for `ToDictionary` extension, is a List of a primitive type (string), I would like to demonstrate converting a List of a complex type (class) into dictionary.

This overload is constructing a dictionary out of keySelector function and elementSelector function ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__)):

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector);
```

For example:

```
public class FooClass 
{
    public int FooKey { get; set; }
    public string FooValue { get; set; }
}

IENumerable<FooClass> foos = new List<FooClass>();
IDictionary<int, string> dict = foos.ToDictionary<int, string>(x=>x.FooKey, x=>x.FooValue);
```